# Visual Basic Script Webbrowser Control

Tags: vbscript, webbrowser-control

how can I make a button for a Webbrowser Control to go back a page without reloading the page?

With reloading it is sth. like this, or?

Webbrowser.GoBack() ??

And without reloading? Is there a posibility?

Thank xou!

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you do a GoBack, it already tries to retreive the page from your computers local cache, so it doesn't send a partial or a full refresh request.

During a browsing session, the WebBrowser control and Windows Internet Explorer maintain a history list of all Web sites visited during a session, unless you specify the navNoHistory flag when you use the Navigate method - in this case you won't be able to go back, so check to see if you can by calling .CanGoBack as that will return a True or False depending on if it can or can't.

Or, you can use the CommandStateChange event to check the enabled state of backward navigation. If the event's CSC_NAVIGATEBACK command is disabled, the beginning of the history list has been reached, and the GoBack method should not be used.

So basically the GoBack method will not do a Refresh by default, however, if you want to do a refresh, there are 2 types of refreshes you can do, I can tell you about those if you want, so just let me know. Also, let me know if you have any other questions or if there is anything else i can help you with relating to this problem or the problem you were trying to solve.

Cheers, speak to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old post, but here is an answer, assuming we have a WPF form with a webBrowser control and a button. Note the button is set to disabled in the xml definition.

```
<Window x:Class="_my_namespace_.frmShowWebData"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GISWorkbenchPro3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="frmShowWebData" Height="450" Width="800" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Cursor="Arrow">

    <DockPanel x:Name="myPanel" Margin="10,24,10,7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:FieldModifier="public" Navigated="webBrowser1_Navigated" LoadCompleted="webBrowser1_OnLoadCompleted" Cursor="Arrow" Height="358" Width="780" />
        <Button x:Name="btnBack" Content="Back"  Width="112" Height="35" Click="btnBack_Click" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="False" Cursor="Hand" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

In the forms xaml.cs file we need to catch the events to turn the Back button on/off depending on the state of the webBrowser control. We also need to track the IsEnabled value of the button. So for the xaml.cs file add a private bool called firstLoad.

```
public frmShowWebData()
{
    firstLoad = true;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.webBrowser1.CanGoBack) { this.webBrowser1.GoBack(); }
    else
    {
        this.btnBack.IsEnabled = false;
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (firstLoad)
    { firstLoad = false; }
    else
    {
        this.btnBack.IsEnabled = true;
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

We also need to check and (re)disable the button if the user navigates forward, then trys to go back to many times.